# Passing a url as a variable into thumbalizr php

Tags: php, variables, screenshot, thumbnails

I am using the Thumbalizr API for capturing website screenshots.

I am trying to pass a url from a variable into the script below where it currently says `"www.google.com"`.

When I try and do `$url = "www.google.com";` and pass that to `$image->request($url);` it seems to fail and retrieves a screenshot but one that suggests the url was unreachable.

Any what am I doing wrong?

Here is the original php in full working order.

```
<?php

    define ("_THUMBALIZR",1);

    require_once("config.inc.php"); // get config and functions
    $image=new thumbalizrRequest(); // create object
    $image->request("www.google.com"); // send request

    if ($image->headers['Status']=="OK" || $image->headers['Status']=="LOCAL") { // if picture is available
     $image->output(); //dump binary image data
    } else {
     print_r($image->headers); // print text result output - you can dump your own "queued" picture here
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Perhaps you should try providing the full url: http:// www. google .com

Comment: The code works with or without the leading http:// so I didn't think that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you show us your current code, IE the one with $url, that may help. In short, $url being used in place of "www.google.com" should not make a difference, as long as $url is being defined correctly and in the current scope (if inside of a function).

Show the current and we can better help you solve this issue.

Comment: This is the code I've been trying to use.

<?php

    $url = "www.google.com";

    define ("_THUMBALIZR",1);

    require_once("config.inc.php"); // get config and functions
    $image=new thumbalizrRequest(); // create object
    $image->request($url); // send request

    if ($image->headers['Status']=="OK" || $image->headers['Status']=="LOCAL") { // if picture is available
     $image->output(); //dump binary image data
    } else {
     print_r($image->headers); // print text result output - you can dump your own "queued" picture here
    }

    ?>

Comment: Put the $url after the config.inc.php, I bet there is a variable being set in there that is "$url" as well and is overwriting your variable.

Comment: Ahh... there is another variable called $url.
I will test that when I get a chance.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be http://www.google.com :)